# React Suppress Warning in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have similar React application code deployed in 2 places (one in a Microfrontend setup and one in a non-Microfrontend setup)

Now when running in the Microfrontend setup, I see the below warning in browser;

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`ParentComponent`) while rendering a different component (`ChildComponent`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `ChildComponent`, follow the stack trace as described
```

But I do not see the same in the non-Microfrontend setup

Not sure what might be suppressing the message. Is it possible to suppress these warning messages via some config in the code?